# Mysql connection error and Ipv6 protocol

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

in notebook of my company, when I connect via VPN to corporate network, I can't connect to MySql server from a c# application with .NET connector, BUT, from another program of customer,via system DSN yes, using same access credentials, ports,tables, etc. Again, for give you others clues, from MySql front, if I select a direct connection, without parameters, I can't connect, instead, if I select a connection via DLL with libMySQL.dll, it is ok.If I ping server name, I have as renspose IPV6 protocol address, non IPV4. May you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: either enable ipv6 on server or disable it on your local machine. or config the DNS to only return ipv4

Comment: For disable it on my local machine, I must do it in LAN properties?

Comment: easiest way is to do it in LAN properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql.Data (aka Connector/NET) doesn't support IPv6: [bug 83649](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83649).

As a workaround, you could consider switching to [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/), an OSS alternative to Connector/NET that fixes this (and many other bugs).